# Texture coordinates in Ogre

Tags: c++, ros, ogre

Currently I am working on ADAS project to visualize road model (lane center, lane boundaries etc) using ROS and OGRE (Object-Oriented Graphics Rendering Engine). Inputs are geometry points (x,y,z).

I am able to draw the lines using Ogre::RenderOperation::OT_TRIANGLE_STRIP.
I have created materials to uniquely visualize solid lines, dotted lies, double solid lines etc..
How do I find texture coordinates for these geometry points?

Current code looks like this:

```
geometry_msgs::Point p0 = _msg.shape_points.front();

    for(int i = 1; i < _msg.shape_points.size(); ++i)
    {
        const geometry_msgs::Point& p1(_msg.shape_points[i]);
        const float dx = p1.x - p0.x;
        const float dy = p1.y - p0.y;
        const float phi = atan2(dy, dx);
        const float wx = sin(phi) * lane_mark_width_;
        const float wy = -cos(phi) * lane_mark_width_;

        if (i == 1)
        {
            lane_boundary_->position(p0.x - wx, p0.y - wy, p0.z);
            lane_boundary_->textureCoord(p0.x , p0.y);

            lane_boundary_->position(p0.x + wx, p0.y + wy, p0.z);
            lane_boundary_->textureCoord(p0.x, p0.y);
        }

        lane_boundary_->position(p1.x - wx, p1.y - wy, p1.z);
        lane_boundary_->textureCoord(p1.x, p1.y);

        lane_boundary_->position(p1.x + wx, p1.y + wy, p1.z);
        lane_boundary_->textureCoord(p1.x, p1.y);

        p0 = p1;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: what's the type of `lane_boundary_`?

Comment: Its a manual object : Ogre::ManualObject *lane_boundary_

Comment: then, I don't know how can this work, because you have to place your drawing calls between `begin` and `end` calls, as described in details in [docs](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_manual_object.html#details). For updating it later use `beginUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

Texture coordinates need to be in the range [0, 1].
Where [0, 0] is at the top left corner of a texture and [1,1] is at the bottom-right.

I'm assuming you want the texture to be mapped to one stripe along the y axis (vertical axis in the texture, Y coordinate range). I'm also assuming your coordinates generation is ordered along the line.

```
geometry_msgs::Point p0 = _msg.shape_points.front();

//Offset in between two points is fixed
const float uv_step = 1.0f / _msg.shape_points.size();

    for(int i = 1; i < _msg.shape_points.size(); ++i)
    {
        const geometry_msgs::Point& p1(_msg.shape_points[i]);
        const float dx = p1.x - p0.x;
        const float dy = p1.y - p0.y;
        const float phi = atan2(dy, dx);
        const float wx = sin(phi) * lane_mark_width_;
        const float wy = -cos(phi) * lane_mark_width_;

        //Compute the vertical texture coordinate
        const float v = i * uv_step;

        if (i == 1)
        {
            lane_boundary_->position(p0.x - wx, p0.y - wy, p0.z);
            //First point is at the top left corner
            lane_boundary_->textureCoord(0.0f, 0.0f);

            lane_boundary_->position(p0.x + wx, p0.y + wy, p0.z);
            //Second point is a the the top right corner
            lane_boundary_->textureCoord(1.0f, 0.0f);
        }

        lane_boundary_->position(p1.x - wx, p1.y - wy, p1.z);
        //Along the y axis on the left
        lane_boundary_->textureCoord(0.0f, v);

        lane_boundary_->position(p1.x + wx, p1.y + wy, p1.z);
        //Along the Y axis on the right
        lane_boundary_->textureCoord(1.0f, v);

        p0 = p1;
    }
```

Make sure you want the same kind of texture mapping. If the texture or coordinates aren't on the right axis, just adjust the code to interpolate on the desired axis.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my case the axis is dynamic. The inputs are from real time system and change according to direction of vehicle.Can we make this implementation dynamic?